# Use HTML5 and JS to get an XML via URL?

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, html

I have an XML file that i access via an URL.

Is it possible to automatically get that file and read it? 
I want to do this so I can later parse it and fill some select lists. The problem I am having is how to in the first place get the XML file and read it? Can i use Ajax or jQuery or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AJAX(Asynchronous JavaScript and *XML*) because that is exactly what it is made for.

You can also use jQuery and use its AJAX Library for easy programming: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/